# Bootstrap Placeholder field doesn't work?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the placeholder attribute on input fields like they do in my Bootstrap examples, but it doesn't show up in my of my elements.  Am I missing something?  Is there some doctype that I'm missing?  I'm using it like in the examples on Boostrap, seemingly a simple attribute, but nothing shows up.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

            <form class="form-search">
                <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Search by Tag">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: This might be a silly question, but did you add the bootstrap css file ?

Comment: Not a silly question, and yes, everything else on the page looks fine.

Comment: Doesn't show on any browser? Which ones are you testing with? It seems alot of people have problem with placeholder on older IE browsers.

Comment: Any of them - FF11, newest Chrome, IE9.  But it shows on the Bootstrap demo pages.  That's why I think maybe it's a doctype issue?

Comment: maybe, have you tried to remove the conditional doctype stuff and testing to see if it works in any of them? your doctype looks pretty legit to me...

Comment: @bluedevil2k works fine for me, can you post a link to your site or port your code to a http://jsfiddle.net so we can take a look?

Comment: Did I miss something or is your form in the HTML head ?

Comment: My stupidity is to blame as usual - I was using one of those "downloadable Bootstrap themes", and this particular theme set the placeholder to #ffffff and the background on inputs to #ffffff.

Comment: @bluedevil2k post your results as an answer and approve it to help future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My stupidity is to blame as usual - I was using one of those "downloadable Bootstrap themes", and this particular theme set the placeholder to #ffffff and the background on inputs to #ffffff.

Comment: I was facing the same problem but when i checked the theme the placeholder color was set to #ffffff. :D , Thanks